# How do i test a method that has a Observable call inside it in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I'm having problem to test the method below:

```
getUserList() {
    this._user.getUsers().subscribe(list =>{
        this.user_list = list;
    });
}
```

The test is written this way:

```
it('User list', () => {
    component.getUserList();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.user_list.length).toBe(1);
});
```

But the test doesn't wait method "component.getUserList()" to populate component.user_list. When i check component.user_list value, it is undefined. There is a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/testing/components/async.html) from Rangle is a nice example.

You can create a mock for `getUsers()`, provide it with TestBed and use `tick` inside `fakeAsync` to simulate the async operation.

```ts
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserComponent } from './user.component';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import {
  async,
  TestBed,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
} from '@angular/core/testing';

const testUsers = [
  // Test data
];

class MockUserService {
  public users = testUsers;

  getUsers() {
    return Observable.of(this.users);
  }
}

describe('Testing User Component', () => {

  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UserComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('Should get users', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.getUserList();
    tick();
    expect(component.user_list).toEqual(testUsers);
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return promise from method in order to be tested, like below:

```
getUserList() {
    return this._user.getUsers().subscribe(list =>{
        this.user_list = list;
        return;
    });
}
```

then in test:

```
it('User list', () => {
    component.getUserList().subscribe(res => {
       fixture.detectChanges();
       expect(component.user_list.length).toBe(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: is this firebase? whats return type of getUsers()?